# ELB Instance Out of service

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

After implementing ELB and Autoscalling on Amazon AWS. There's a wierd issue happens and we don't know either the reason or the fix.

- We installed Auto Scalling configuration to add instance of AMI ID of Windows 2008 R2 x64, SQL Express and IIS.
- We also let the ELB to check health on "/", normal configuration and supposed that the IIS is running normally.
- But as soon as the instance started, it is shown as "Out Of Service" at ELB.
- Status turns into "In Service" suddenly after sometime.
- What's the reason for such issue?
- Is it possible to make it available in no time? "As for sure when instance is started it's needed to be load balanced istantly"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The health check in your ELB has five parameters:

```
Ping Target:          HTTP:80/
Timeout:              5 seconds 
Interval:             30 seconds
Unhealthy Threshold:  2
Healthy Threshold:    10
```

When a new instance is started it is assumed to be in an "unhealthy" state and must successfully respond to **Healthy Threshold** requests, each of which are separated by **Interval** before it will be included in the pool.

To reduce the time a new instance takes to be considered "healthy", lower the **Interval** and the **Healthy Threshold**.

Note that this increases the possibility of an instance "flapping" in and out of service when it is overloaded.